# Use data from CombiTimeTable in OpenModelica to operate with the matrix?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, dymola

I want to use the data imported in a CombiTimeTable matrix (OpenModelica reads the data, so no problem here). It's a matrix of 37 rows and 4 columns, let's call it M.

For example, I would like multiplicate each row for an element from a vector. I've try this for the next block but it dosen't work:

```
model Forces

Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput M[:,:];
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput vector[:];
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput A[:,:];


 equation
  for i in 1:37 loop
    A[1, i] = M[i, 1]*0.1;
    A[2, i] = M[i, 2]*vector[1];
  end for;
 end Forces
```

M and vector would come from the component CombiTimeTable. Any sugestions?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your code has many flaws. `M` is defined as a scalar, not a matrix. Use `[:,:]` to define a matrix. Similar for `A` and `vector`. `Coeff` is not defined. If `vector` is a vector, you can not index it with `[1, 2]`. What has it to do with the `CombiTimeTable`? What exactly is the question?

Comment: Thank you Marco! I apreciate your answer :) Well, my question is how to use data loaded on CombiTimeTable (OM reads it like a matrix) on a model created by me. With this model, I intend to operate with this matrix and another vector, including both as an input. With that operations I want to obtain another matrix A. In the example, the first row of A is equal to the first row of M multiplied by 0.1 A's second row is equal to M multiplied by the first component of the vector.  I've edited the code with your sugestions but still it dosen't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not show the `CombiTimeTable` part, so I replaced the connectors with simple variables to create a minimal example.

After doing that, your code almost works. The only problems are missing size constraints. Modelica tools must be able to determine the size of vectors, matrices and arrays at compilation time. This can be done by:

- specifying sizes using literals, like `M[2,3]`
- specifying sizes using constants or evaluated parameters, like `A[m,n]` with `m` and `n` being parameters or constants
- specifying sizes using the size of a non-scalar variable of known size, like `A[2,3]` and `B[size(A,1), size(A,2)]`
- using unknown size operator `:`, but assigning a modifier equation which allows to determine the size, like `A[:,:] = [1, 2; 3, 4]`

With the methods above you can set the size for each dimension. Keep in min that sizes cannot change during simulation. If changes that gives a new size, the model has to be recompiled.

Applying those methods and using some assumptions from your `for` loop, a working example would be:

```
model Forces
  Real M[:,2] = [1, 2; 3, 4] "Two columns are needed (due to usage in for loop), but amount of rows can vary";
  Real vector[:] = {1} "Vector of arbitrary size, but we just use element 1 below";
  Real A[2, size(M, 1)] "New matrix with 2 rows and variable amount of columns, depending on M";
equation 
  for i in 1:size(M, 1) loop
    A[1, i] = M[i, 1]*0.1;
    A[2, i] = M[i, 2]*vector[1];
  end for;
end Forces;
```

Comment: Thank you Marco, you're so kind :) This is exactly what I was missing. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

The original question is rather unprecise, but according to your comment to the question by @marco, this could be the code you are looking for:

```
model Forces

Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput M[37,4] = ones(37,4);
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput vector[:] = {2,3,4};
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput A[size(M,1), size(M,2)];

equation 
  A[:,1] = M[:,1] * 0.1;
  A[:,2] = M[:,2] * vector[1];
  A[:,3:end] = M[:,3:end];

end Forces;
```

Note:

- You will likely get warnings as inputs have a binding equations. This is because `M` and `vector` are inputs but values are assigned in the model itself, which is usually not done as they should be provided from outside the model.
- It would likely be better to define `M` and `vector` as a `parameter` in this case. To do so change the code to the one below (note that parameters are not allowed to change over time, so potentially you have to use a mix of inputs and parameters):

```
model Forces

parameter Real M[37,4] = ones(37,4);
parameter Real vector[:] = {2,3,4};
parameter Real A[size(M,1), size(M,2)];

equation 
  A[:,1] = M[:,1] * 0.1;
  A[:,2] = M[:,2] * vector[1];
  A[:,3:end] = M[:,3:end];

end Forces;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Markus!! :) Your comment helped me in fixing the binding errors.